# How can I consume a RABL API from within the application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, rabl

I'm working on exposing an API using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). Exposing the views is easy enough, but I've run into trouble having my own application consume those views.

For example, assume I have an endpoint at `http://example.com/api/articles`, which produces a JSON representation of the articles.

In my `ArticlesController#index` action, I wish to render a (HAML) view that shows a list of the articles. Rather than duplicate the logic from `ArticlesApiController#index`, I want to simply use that data—i.e., I want to say "go get this data from the `/articles` API endpoint," and then pass that data to the HAML view.

How  can I do that? Or, is this the wrong way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Watch this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl) on RABL.

In your view you can add the data from RABL as follows(taken from railscast sample):

```
<div id="articles" 
   data-articles="<%= render(template: "articles/index.json.rabl") %>">
```

**Note**

You can make the data access even more simple by using the [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem.

In your controller

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all 

  # initialize the JS variable upon HTML request
  gon.rabl if request.format == Mime::HTML

end
```

Now you can access the data in the javascript as follows:

```
alert(gon.articles)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what I'm trying to do is *avoid* having to duplicate the logic of figuring out what "all the articles means" (even though it's trivial). My API already knows what all the articles are, and I'd like my controller to just pull it from the API. I wonder if I should just step back and put the "all articles" logic in the articles model and then just use that both in the API and in the main controller?

Comment: Look at the edit's I made to the controller action. There is no duplication of logic. When the HTML request is made JS variable is set. The solution is based on the assumption that the authentication/authorization for the action happens in pre filters.

Comment: The OP isn't asking about how to access the information in javascript. His Rails application is consuming an external JSON API. He wants to fetch the json from the API, put it in some object, and pass that object to the haml views. Without much duplication or boilerplate code.

Comment: @JoeVanDyk, that is not how am interpreting. The `index` action of the articles controller is exposed as an API. When a user calls the same action with `html` extension he wants to consume his own API rather than making the authorization decisions again.